# Calling Elasticsearch Template Query using NEST?

Tags: templates, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net, elasticsearch-template

Is there a way to call Template Query using NEST? Is there any examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [search template](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-template.html#search-template) endpoint isn't mapped in NEST yet, and poses a bit of a challenge since it's very different to how queries are normally constructed.  We're actually working on this now ([in this branch](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/commits/feauture/search-template)) and are *hoping* to get this functionality in the upcoming 1.1 release.  Here's a link to the [original issue](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/issues/635) for tracking purposes.

EDIT:  Forgot to mention, the endpoint is available on the low-level Elasticsearch.Net client, which you can access via `ElasticClient`:

```
var client = new ElasticClient(...);
client.Raw.SearchTemplate(...);
```

Comment: I knew low-level elasticsearch.net provided this but was curious about on the NEST side. Thanks bunch for your confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

The search template endpoint has been mapped in NEST 2.x.

There is a general example about templating here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/template-query-usage.html

Here is some information about how inline templates can be used in a phrase suggestion with the collate option:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/suggest-usage.html

Here is an issue on GitHub I posted with some information on how to save templates to Elastic:
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/2176

Here's a general example of how to use NEST:

```
var templateRequest= new PutSearchTemplateDescriptor(new Id("my_template"));

templateRequest.Template("{\"multi_match\":{\"query\":{\"query\":\"{{suggestion}}\",\"fields\":[\"field1\",\"field2\"]}}}");

var response = ElasticClient.PutSearchTemplate(templateRequest);
```

When using the template in a suggest collate:

```
.Collate(c => c
    .Query(q => q
        .Indexed("my_template")
    )
    .Prune()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another question on similiar lines, Is PutSearchTemplateDescriptor the write method to call a pre-regsitered template?

I have registered the template to the .scripts but unable to find the right method to call the template from NEST client